# Writing R function with if enviornment

Tags: r, function, gsub

I am trying to write a function which does different things, depending on the second argument. But I am getting an error all the time. Depending on the dimension of the matrix, the function should perform different tasks. Here is an example

```
x<-cbind(X1,X2,X3)

function<-function(x,hnrstr){
  if (hnrstr<-1){ 
    x<-data.frame(X1=x[1],X2=x[2],X3=x[3])
    y<-x 
    y[ ,"X2","X3"]<- gsub(" {2, }"," ",y[ ,"X2","X3"])       
  }

  if (hnrstr<-2){ 
    x<-data.frame(X1=x[1],X2=x[2])
    P<-x 
  }  
  if (hnrstr<-1){
    x<-y
  }
  if (hnrstr<-2){
    x<-P  
  }
  return(x)
}

apply(x,c(3,3), function(x,1))
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Comment: Can you add some space around your operators so we can tell if/when you're using a less than symbol `<` and when you're using an assignment operator `<-`? Also, for such types of problems, I generally also consider `switch` as an alternative.

Comment: I think in your if statements, the test should be e.g. if (hnrstr==2), not (hnrstr<-2)

Comment: I put in the switch opertaor. `switch(hnrstr,
         "1"={ .....}, "2"={....})` But its still the same error for `apply(x,1,strassestand(x,"1"))`

Comment: The apply statement should be `apply(x, 1, strassestand, hnrstr=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hnrstr<-1` is assigning the value of 1 to `hnrstr`. You do not want this in an `if` statement.  You either meant "test that hnrstr is less than minus one", in which case add some whitespace.  `hnrstr < -1`, or you meant "test that hnrstr is equal to one", in which case use double equals, `hnsstr == 1`.

---

If `X1`, `X2` and `X3` are vectors, then `x` will be a matrix.  That is, it has two dimensions.  that means that later, after you've assigned `y <- x` (why do you need to do this?) `y[ ,"X2","X3"])` doesn't make much sense because it implies that there are 3 dimensions, not two.  This is what is causing the error.   Did you mean `y[, c("X2","X3")])`?

---

`gsub` accepts a vector, so after you've changed the previous code, you also need to change the call to that function.  Do you want to pass it the second column or the third column or both (one after the other)?

---

Those second if blocks look pointless.  Have a think about how you can remove them.

```
if (hnrstr<-1){
x<-y
}
if (hnrstr<-2){
x<-P  
}
```

---

You don't need a `return` statement at the end of the function.  R automatically returns the last value that was calculated in the function.

---

As Colin said, don't try and call your function "function".  That's just asking for trouble.  Change the line

```
function <- function(x,hnrstr){
```

Comment: Thing is, I want to delete blank spaces out of a string with gesub If i use `x[ ,c("X2","X3")]<- gsub(" {2, }"," ",x[ ,c("X2","X3")])`  R just overwrites X2 and X3 with 1, it works fine if I use gsub only on a single vector.

Comment: I want to use gsub on both vectors of the dataframe. I need X1 to put some if commands on some gsub commands.

Comment: You might also want to mention: `function <- function` ;)

Comment: @user2963882 You can apply `gsub` using a loop (either a `for` loop, or using the `lapply` function).  Before you do that, I suggest that you have a practice with indexing.