# R switch in function

Tags: r, function, switch-statement

I am trying to build a switch into an R function. The function should perform `gsub` commands on a data frame, depending on the dimension of the input.

Here is some example data:

```
X1 <- c("NUERNBERG","BERLIN","WERNE")
X2 <- c("REGENSBURGERSTR","WARSCHAUERSTRASSE","WIEHAGEN")
X3 <- c("89","23","1")
x <- cbind(X1,X2,X3)
```

and my function:

```
function <- function(x, hnrstr){
  switch(hnrstr,
         "1" = {
           x <- data.frame(X1=x[1],X2=x[2],X3=x[3])
           y <- x 
           y[ ,"X2","X3"] <- gsub(" {2, }"," ",y[ ,"STRASSE","HAUSNUMMER"])  
           x <- y
         },
         "2" = {
           x <- data.frame(X1=x[1],X2=x[2])
           P <- x 
           P[ ,"X2"] <- gsub(" {2, }"," ",y[ ,"X2"])
           x <- P 
         }
  )
  return(x)
}

apply(x,1,function, hnrstr="1")
```

which gives the error:

```
Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Comment: I guess `y[ ,"X2","X3"]` should be `y[ ,c("X2","X3")]`? In any case, that's producing the error.

Comment: @user2963882 You also get an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20068809/2886003) in the other question with if statements

Comment: Voting to close as a dup, since the problem isn't with switch. The answer is given in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20068809/2886003